# Accessing production key for Amadeus Developer Self-Service API

Tags: amadeus

Has anyone be able to get a production key for the Self-Service API? I wasn't able to complete the form request, always throws an error at step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, Amadeus for Developers Self-Service is still in beta version. We are actually fixing this issue and making some improvments before releasing (in the coming days) the new version.
Changes are coming to the portal and the APIs that’s why it may not be perfectly stable yet.

### EDIT

The new version has been released. You can now move from the test environment to the production environment.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please add expiration date for reservations, that's a very useful information.

Comment: I ment expiration date for the LowFare api.

Comment: Update on the answer: the new version has been deployed you can now move to production.

Comment: I did move to production (you should specify somewhere the endpoint for it). Thank you.